# How to handle an UIScrollView in an UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to use an `UIScrollView` in an `UIScrollView`. I think it would be clearer with a
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5B6k.jpg)

The black border is the border of the screen, the purple is the first `UIScrollView` and the blue is the second `UIScrollView`. The arrows show the direction of the scroll.

When I try to put the second `UIScrollView` in the first with a different scrolling direction, the second show the content twice... I made a [video](https://vimeo.com/user87689481/review/282483295/f3cc4d05e8)

Comment: Use a UIView inside every scrollview for the proper content size and handle scrolling of both.

Comment: You need to share some code. What does "it doesn't work" mean, specifically?

Answer (score 1):

I have created design for you to explain how to add scroll view inside scroll view.
Here see the following image with constraints.

> **Note: This is static view not dynamic, This is create to clear concept of ScrollView inside ScrollView.** If you are planning to make ScrollView with design then you need to do some more study on AutoLayout with ScrollView.

[image: UIScrollView inside UIScrollView]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it was helpful. But now I have another problem... -> https://vimeo.com/user87689481/review/282483295/f3cc4d05e8

Comment: @ValentinDusollier, As per your video, at top, there should be collection view with horizontal scrolling for multiple text that you are scrolling, not scroll view.